# why can't I write just meter instead of "meter' in python 2.7.14?

Tags: python

I use python 2.7.14..... I wrote this code in python andriod Qpython3 version....but when I used it in python 2.7.14 the programme accepts strings with these " " or ' '  .......in Qpython3 I just had to to write meter....here I have to write "meter"  .....
any suggestion how to solve it?

here is the code:

```
import time


print("This is a converter.Here, you have to spell the whole name of a unit otherwise  it wont work")
print(' ')  
def converter():
 a=float(input("Enter a number:"    )) 
 print(" ") 
 x=input("from:"    )  
 print(" ")  
 y=input("to:"    )
 print(" ") 
 if x=="meter" and y=="kilometer" or x=="gram" and y=="kilogram":
    print(a/1000)
 elif x=="kilometer" and y=="meter" or x=="kilogram" and y=="gram":
    print(a*1000)
 #just keep adding more convertions starting with elifs inside the define function
 #and keep the else statement at the end of all elifs...
 #and that converter() function call it at the all end just once...
 #infact dont do anything escept adding elif statements....good luck 
 #dont change that float it accepts both integer and float
 else  :
            print("wrong")


 print(" ")
 print('To continue type "next",Thank you.')
 print(" ")
 print('To exit type "quit",Thank you.')
 print(" ")
 s=input()
 if s=="next":
    print(" ")
    converter()
 elif s=="quit":
    time.sleep(1)
 else:
    print("I Can't understand your command")
converter()
```

Comment: `meter` would be a reference name, whereas `"meter"` is a string object.  Does your question refer to the response to the `input()` typed by the user?

Comment: Please show the other code.

Comment: That is the difference between a string and a variable; you should look up the basics of programming. Anyway, if you want to write meter without quotes, write at the beginning of your code `meter = "meter"`, and then use `meter` without quotes

Comment: show the rest of the code

Comment: In python2.7 you want to use `raw_input()`, in python3 you want to use `input()`. This comes up too frequently to bother even flagging as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `input()` in Python 2.x. You should rather use `raw_input()` which returns a string instead of referencing a variable.

So your edited code should look like:

```
import time


print("This is a converter.Here, you have to spell the whole name of a unit otherwise  it wont work")
print(' ')

def converter():
    a=float(raw_input("Enter a number:"    )) 
    print(" ") 
    x=raw_input("from:"    )  
    print(" ")  
    y=raw_input("to:"    )
    print(" ") 
    if x=="meter" and y=="kilometer" or x=="gram" and y=="kilogram":
       print(a/1000)
    elif x=="kilometer" and y=="meter" or x=="kilogram" and y=="gram":
        print(a*1000)
        #just keep adding more convertions starting with elifs inside the define function
        #and keep the else statement at the end of all elifs...
        #and that converter() function call it at the all end just once...
        #infact dont do anything escept adding elif statements....good luck 
        #dont change that float it accepts both integer and float
     else:
          print("wrong")


     print(" ")
     print('To continue type "next",Thank you.')
     print(" ")
     print('To exit type "quit",Thank you.')  
     print(" ")
     s=raw_input()
     if s=="next":
         print(" ")
         converter()
     elif s=="quit":
         time.sleep(1)
     else:
         print("I Can't understand your command")
     converter()
```

some improvement proposals:

1.: Better format your code. I have done it for you.

2.: Here: `elif s=="quit":` you can write: `import sys` and `sys.exit()` to exit the program